# When are constexpr function templates instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, constexpr

I'm working on a proposal to make the functional header functions `constexpr`. (`std::invoke`, `std::reference_wrapper`, `std::bind`, `std::mem_fn`, `std::not_fn`)

- [Preview of the proposal](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/bebuch/proposals/blob/master/Add%20constexpr%20to%20functional%20header%20functions.html)

I've learned that adding `constexpr` can break existing code because `constexpr` functions are eagerly instantiated.

```
template<class T>
int f(T){
    return T::not_existing_member;
}

template<class T>
constexpr int g(T){
    return T::not_existing_member;
}

int main(){
    decltype(f(0)) a; // Well-formed
    decltype(g(0)) b; // Ill-formed if the function body is instantiated
}
```

GCC compiles this code, clang doesn't. I describe in [my proposal](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/bebuch/proposals/blob/master/Add%20constexpr%20to%20functional%20header%20functions.html) how you can handle the eager instantiation with overloads using the example of `std::bind`.

Can you tell me where in the standard it is described when a compiler *has to* and when it is *allowed to* instantiate a function template?

More precisely I want to know if in the following example the identical behavior of GCC and clang is enforced by the standard or is implementation defined:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo{
    constexpr int f(){
        return 0;
    }

    constexpr int f()const{
        return T::not_existing_member;
    }
};

int main(){
    /* constexpr */ Foo<int> foo;
    foo.f(); // Ill-formed with, Well-formed without constexpr by the standard?
}
```

Both GCC and clang compile the code if `foo` is not `constexpr` and both reject it  if it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example #1 is active [CWG issue 1581](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581). It is currently not completely specified what the correct behavior *should* be. The direction seems to be that `constexpr` instantiation should be eager, but this needs to be clarified at some point in the future.

Example #2 is straightforward: invoking `int Foo<int>::f() const` is ill-formed. That happens when your `foo` object is `const` but not when it's non-`const`. Member functions of class templates are only instantiated when used, and if your `Foo<int>` object is non-`const`, we never instantiate the `const` member function, so the code is well-formed. `constexpr` isn't relevant here.

Comment: Ah yes. I had an error in reasoning about example #2. With ´foo´ being ´constexpr´ it also becomes ´const´ of course and so the ´const´ overload is called directly. Thank you very much!